# Legendary Lord ranks any effect?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

At the moment I have a champion in my Chaos army that has Train army. But because of the training my Legendary Lord is getting ranks as well. 
At the moment he is a rank 2 unit legendary lord. Do the ranks have any effect on leaders and heroes?

Screenshot added:
[image]

Comment: It is possible that these ranks increase the stats of the unit. You should be able to check if the stats are increased in the unit profile (a green part is added to the stat bar). It will be mixed up with the stat increases provided by perks so you need to be aware of what perks you have and calculate your expected stats and see if the actual stats are any higher than this. I think unit levels only increase leadership, melee attack and defense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, legendary lords, lords or also heroes can't get ranks like a normal unit.
That its clearly a bug and maybe, when you asked that bug can appear and now I hope you cant.
Lords, LL or heroes ONLY can get "ranks" leveling up and having their own stats and skills. You can modify that with leveling more, adding items or getting skills which modify thet stat, which is usually the "yellow perks" on the skills menu.

I didnt see this but I see another bugs that is just cheat or impossible to do.

Comment: If you had a character with the trait to grant experience per round for your army, this could happen before they patched it.

Comment: I had that trait on many campaings and I never get this bug, but this is only a bug.